# Debian system doesn't mount or find /sbin/init during boot

Tags: debian, initramfs, sysvinit, initrd

I'm getting the dreaded "target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init", am getting dropped into initramfs busybox prompt, and am unable to boot.  This is after upgrading to the latest 4.9.0-3 kernel on Debian. It was working perfectly before.

Approximately, it says:

```
Scanning for BtrFs filesystem
usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type f] [-i] [-n] device directory
target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
mount: no such file or directory
```

I tried fsck on the disk; it is fine. (I also tried fsck -f to make sure. No go.)

I tried manually setting root=/dev/sda4 during boot in the grub menu. Again, didn't help.

I can successfully mount /dev/sda4 from a live CD:

```
$ mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
$ mount --bind /proc/ /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /sys/ /mnt/sys
```

and chroot into it:

```
$ chroot /mnt
```

And I can see that /sbin/init does indeed exist:

```
# ls /sbin/init
/sbin/init
```

I can even run it:

```
# /sbin/init
Usage: init {-e VAR[=VAL] | [-t SECONDS] {0|1|2|3|4|5|6|S|s|Q|q|A|a|B|b|C|c|U|u}}
```

Within the chroot, I tried running "update-initramfs" and "update-grub". Both ran successfully, but neither helped.

It seems as if "update-initramfs" is generating a bogus **initrd** that won't mount the root system properly.

It is running initramfs=0.120+deb8u3 and sysvinit-core=2.88dsf-59.9.

It is not running cryptofs nor btrfs.  It is, however, running on a Mac, if that matters.

Comment: could it be udev? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305343/debian-jessie-hanging-on-boot

Comment: Not sure.  udev=230-7~bpo8+2 which seems to work on my other computers.  (Attempting to downgrade this via apt-get removes a whole bunch of stuff, so I left it.)

Comment: It is not about rebuilding it, but having it enabled on boot

Comment: It is enabled on boot.  Otherwise, I would not have been able to mount /dev/sda4 by hand from the **initramfs** prompt.  In fact, as far as I can tell, the entire /dev is being populated in full and correctly.  It appears to be a problem in the /init script within the busybox environment.  Still investigating...

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know exactly what's wrong in your situation, but this message in your output is suspicious:

```
usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type f] [-i] [-n] device directory
```

It looks to me that it is not mounting your root filesystem and this error is the result of it trying.

Have a read of https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug to see how you can debug it further. The last section on "Saving debug information" might reveal enough to suggest what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was a bug or something wrong with initramfs=0.120+deb8u3 (jessie-backports) because when I upgraded to initramfs=0.130 (stable), it boots.  (My next step would have been to upgrade udev to stable, despite it removing a bunch of packages; thankfully, I didn't have to take that step.)

Comment: If you think there is a bug, you should report it.